# Print certain value from a JSON response

Tags: c#, json

Just started playing with C# again and I'm not able to get over this.

I have the following JSON content:

```
{
  "type": "success",
  "picks": [
    {
      "aftermarket": {
        "domain": "ao38t8u4h.com",
        "fast_transfer": false,
        "price": 0,
        "status": "notfound",
        "type": "",
        "username": ""
      },
      "domain": "ao38t8u4h.com",
      "info": "",
      "priority": 1,
      "status": {
        "available": true,
        "lookupType": "EPP",
        "name": "ao38t8u4h.com",
        "premium": false
      },
      "tld": "com",
      "type": "domain"
    },
    {
      "aftermarket": {
        "domain": "ao38t8u4h.net",
        "fast_transfer": false,
        "price": 0,
        "status": "notfound",
        "type": "",
        "username": ""
      },
      "domain": "ao38t8u4h.net",
      "info": "",
      "priority": 2,
      "status": {
        "available": true,
        "lookupType": "EPP",
        "name": "ao38t8u4h.net",
        "premium": false
      },
      "tld": "net",
      "type": "domain"
    },
    {
      "aftermarket": {
        "domain": "ao38t8u4h.dev",
        "fast_transfer": false,
        "price": 0,
        "status": "notfound",
        "type": "",
        "username": ""
      },
      "domain": "ao38t8u4h.dev",
      "info": "",
      "priority": 3,
      "status": {
        "available": true,
        "lookupType": "EPP",
        "name": "ao38t8u4h.dev",
        "premium": false
      },
      "tld": "dev",
      "type": "domain"
    },
    {
      "aftermarket": {
        "domain": "ao38t8u4h.ai",
        "fast_transfer": false,
        "price": 0,
        "status": "notfound",
        "type": "",
        "username": ""
      },
      "domain": "ao38t8u4h.ai",
      "info": "",
      "priority": 4,
      "status": {
        "available": true,
        "lookupType": "EPP",
        "name": "ao38t8u4h.ai",
        "premium": false
      },
      "tld": "ai",
      "type": "domain"
    },
    {
      "aftermarket": {
        "domain": "ao38t8u4h.org",
        "fast_transfer": false,
        "price": 0,
        "status": "notfound",
        "type": "",
        "username": ""
      },
      "domain": "ao38t8u4h.org",
      "info": "",
      "priority": 5,
      "status": {
        "available": true,
        "lookupType": "EPP",
        "name": "ao38t8u4h.org",
        "premium": false
      },
      "tld": "org",
      "type": "domain"
    }
  ]
}
```

What I'd like to do is obtain the value in `["picks"][0]["status"]["premium"]`. What I'd do in Python would be to get the response and then simply `print(var["picks"][0]["status"]["premium"])` to print the value; however, I don't know how to accomplish this in C#.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace testing
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string domain = "ao38t8u4h";
                string url = "https://rtb.namecheapapi.com/api/picks/" + domain;
                string responseBody = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
                var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseBody);
                Console.WriteLine(json);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch(HttpRequestException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");
                Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ", e.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://quicktype.io/?l=cs&r=json2csharp - 99% of JSON questions are solved more simply by first deserialising them to their concrete types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Json.Net supports the syntax you are used to if you use [`JTokens`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm).

```
JToken jt = JToken.Parse(responseBody);
Console.WriteLine(jt["picks"][0]["status"]["premium"]);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BssMHq

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @mjwills:
Deserialize json. Then print value like so:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Value = {json.Picks[0].Status.Premium}");
```